# Create multiple directory and subdirectory from multiple txt files

Tags: bash, scripts

I have three text files:

`years.txt` containing:

```
2003
2004
2005
2006
...
```

`type.txt` containing:

```
cpu
case
ram
hd
...
```

`month.txt` containing:

```
jenuary
february
march
...
```

Now, I want to create the year folders, inside each of them, create the type folders and into each type, create the days folders.

For example:

```
2003

    cpu

       jenuary

       february

       ...

    case

       jenuary

       february

       ...
```

etc.

I must use bin bash script.
I think I must read each file, line by line, and store each line into an array...
Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script that would do the same

```
#! /bin/bash

cat years.txt | \
        # Read years.txt line by line. Each line is stored in $folder1.
        while read folder1; do

                cat type.txt | \
                        # Read type.txt line by line. Each line is stored in $folder2.
                        while read folder2; do

                                cat month.txt | \
                                        # Read month.txt line by line. Each line is stored in $folder3.                   
                                        while read folder3; do
                                                # Create/modify $path variable.
                                                path="$folder1/$folder2/$folder3"

                                                # Create the directory.
                                                mkdir -p "$path"
                                        done
                        done
        done
```

***Some help taken from:*** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642191/read-line-by-line-in-bash-script